# anything slider (several problems)

Tags: jquery, css, slider, anythingslider

I got several problems that i already spent hours on and obviously i really need help.

I use anythingslider for a content slideshow. You can find it here: http://ontwikkelomgeving.wijzijnblits.nl/fobservices/slider

Now the problems:

1. there is a flickering when there is a transition. (biggest problem)
2. you can't see when a button is active (it should set the background img to top)
3. when i click a button, it shows the active state, but once i hover it it is gone. Also, if i click another button and i dont hover the first one, then i get 2 active states.

Can somebody help me with either of these problems?
Thanks a bunch in advance!!

Comment: You should at lest show the HTML and the relevant part of the jQuery code. I've looked on the slider webpage and that seems to work OK, so woithout knowing how you are using the slider, it's difficult to know what to say.

Answer (score 3):

Probably **not** the  best answer.

But maybe it will be faster to try [this slider](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/), as I remember it easy to use and fast to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the flicker problem you are referring to, but the active slide navigation is because a problem with the css.

In the css, all of the color/background settings are separated out and put at the top, so this one bit of css was being defined several times. So here is the complete, updated anythingslider.css file:

```
/*
    AnythingSlider v1.4.1+ Default (base) theme

    By Chris Coyier: http://css-tricks.com
    with major improvements by Doug Neiner: http://pixelgraphics.us/
    based on work by Remy Sharp: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/
*/

/******* SET DEFAULT DIMENSIONS HERE ********/
#sliderholder {
    background-image: url(../images/bg-slider.jpg);
    width: 533px;
    height: 270px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-top: 14px;
}
div.anythingSlider {
    width: 519px;
    height: 208px;

}

/****** SET COLORS HERE *******/
/* Default State */
div.anythingSlider .thumbNav a {
    background: url(../images/thenav.png) center bottom;
    color: #fff;
}

div.anythingSlider .start-stop {
    background-color: #ff000;
    color: #fff;
}
div.anythingSlider .start-stop.playing {
    background-color: #800;
}
div.anythingSlider .start-stop:hover, div.anythingSlider .start-stop.hover {
    color: #ddd;
}

/* Active State */
div.anythingSlider .start-stop {
    background-color: #080;
    color: #fff;
}
div.anythingSlider .start-stop.playing {
    background-color: #d00;
}
div.anythingSlider .start-stop:hover, div.anythingSlider .start-stop.hover {
    color: #fff;
}

/**** DO NOT CHANGE BELOW THIS LINE ****/
/* anythingSlider viewport window */
div.anythingSlider .anythingWindow {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
/* wrapper: 45px right & left padding for the arrows, 28px @ bottom for navigation */
div.anythingSlider {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}
/* anythingSlider base UL */
ul.anythingBase {
    background: transparent;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.anythingBase li.panel {
    background: transparent;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Navigation Links */
div.anythingSlider .anythingControls { outline: 0; }
div.anythingSlider .thumbNav { margin: 0; }
div.anythingSlider .thumbNav li { display: inline; }
div.anythingSlider .thumbNav a {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 4px;
    height: 21px;
    width: 24px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
div.anythingSlider .thumbNav a:hover, div.anythingSlider .thumbNav a.cur {
    background-position: center top;
}
/* slider autoplay right-to-left, reverse order of nav links to look better */
div.anythingSlider.rtl .thumbNav a { float: left; } /* reverse order of nav links */
div.anythingSlider.rtl .thumbNav { float: left; }    /* move nav link group to left */
/* div.anythingSlider.rtl .start-stop { float: right; } */ /* move start/stop button - in case you want to switch sides */

div.anythingSlider, div.anythingSlider .anythingWindow, div.anythingSlider .thumbNav a, div.anythingSlider .arrow a, div.anythingSlider .start-stop {
    transition-duration: 0;
    -o-transition-duration: 0;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0;
}

.textSlide { margin: 15px; width:489px; height:178px; color:#fff;  }
```